# Custom UITableViewCell Positions

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to programmatically create a `UIImageView` and place it near another static control that was positioned with IB. My code is like:

```
iv.frame = CGRectMake(cell.positionedLabel.bounds.origin.x - 20, cell.positionedLabel.bounds.size.height, 26, 26);
```

But the x of the label added with IB is always 0.0.

I'm doing this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Does anyone know why the bounds aren't set for this item yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds origin is almost always zero.  The only common exception is UIScrollView and its subclasses will set a non-zero bounds origin to offset their contents (that's what contentOffset does).

Anyway, use frame instead of bounds: `cell.positionedLabel.frame.origin.x`, or better yet `CGRectGetMinX(cell.positionedLabel.frame)` because `CGRectGetMinX` will correctly handle nonstandard CGRects (like rects with negative width and height).